# Putting the rowmapper inside the domain class

Tags: java, data, class-design, domain-model, spring

Normally in java the `RowMapper` is placed in its own class.

Instead, what about this design, putting the `RowMapper` inside each domain object, and giving all of them a consistent name:

```
public class Address {
    private String city;
        public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }


    public static class ThisRowMapper implements RowMapper<Address> {
        @Override
        public Address mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Address address = new Address(); 
            address.setCity(rs.getString("CITY"));
            return address;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the query:

```
new Address.ThisRowMapper()
```

The pro here is that the `RowMapper` is right next to the domain object, so it's easy(er) to make sure all the fields are being mapped.

Are there any cons to this design I should know about?

Followup question (but the first question is my main question):

I could take the above a step further and add:

```
public static final ThisRowMapper thisRowMapper = new ThisRowMapper();
```

Then use it:

```
Address.thisRowMapper
```

This lets me avoid creating the `RowMapper` object time, which is probably not that big a deal, but since it doesn't hurt readability, perhaps it's worthwhile?

And cons for this 2nd option?

Comment: Imho it doesn't really belong to the domain class but rather in your data access layer. Regarding creating 1 or more instances, that is personal preference I guess.  As long as it isn't stateful you could create a single instance out of it. However with java 8 it is quite easy to use a lambda expression instead of creating an actual class out of it.

Comment: Since ResultSet is stable and well abstracted, putting the rowmapper in the domain object makes good sense to me.  That way when you add a field to the object, easy (and a reminder) to add a column to the database.  Also, you can possibly make the fields private with no need for getters and setters.  In fact, your domain object could even be immutable.